# Space Between CardView

Tags: android, cardview

I need to add space between `CardView`.

I tried to use the `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding` and it doesn't work. Any help?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/all_restaurant_card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"

        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Comment: How about regular padding/margins? Depending on where you want your space added.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"  //4dp is recommended
```

Answer (score 1):

I try bellow code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
>
```

1. whatever value set in **layout_marginBottom**, android always have a little space between 2 cardviews. I think **layout_marginBottom** doen't affect the size of space.
2. **card_view:cardUseCompatPadding** should set to true.
3. **card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap** should set to true to affect **card_view:cardCornerRadius**, and different value of **cardCornerRadius** cause different space between 2 cardviews.